# Saving a file to a network in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, save, qfile

I need to save a file to my company's network. This needs to be coded into my application not using a File Dialog box or anything. When I save the file without specifying a path it saves it completely fine in the directory that my application is in but when I try to do it the network nothing happens. This is what I have to save it.

```
QFile outfile;
outfile.setFileName("//DTPRIMARY/MyFile.htm");
outfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QTextStream out(&outfile);
out << textEdit->toHtml();
out.flush();
outfile.close();
```

I actually want to save it here `\\DTPRIMARY\Inetpub\wwwroot` but took out the other folders thinkging that could have been part of the problem but it wasn't. And I'm using '/'s instead of '\'s because thats what a few places said to do (I've never really understood why file paths have to use '\' or '/' though so it could be wrong idk.)

Does anyone know how to do this/what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

UNC paths should work perfectly normally, you can test this with a local file eg `"\\?\C:\MyFile.htm"` would be a file called MyFile.htm in the top of the C drive

Normally the path would be `\\machine\share`  eg `\\dtprimaray\share\MyFile.htm`

The reason for using "/" is that the C language uses \ to mean the next char is special, so \t is tab, \n is newline. DOS was copied (sorry *influenced by*) an earlier OS that used "/" for file separators and Microsoft didn't want DOS to look too much like a copy. It's been a source of bugs ever since.

You can use `\\` to say to C the next \ is really a \ - but it's easy to make mistakes when you have to write  `\\\\` to mean `\\` and `\\` to mean `\` - so Windows lets you use `/`

Just tested it on my machine

```
QFile file("//machinename/downloads/MyFile.htm");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write("blah");
file.close();
```

Comment: Does this actually work on windows? AFAIK `QFile` requires the remote directory to be mounted locally on *nix systems unless something has changed since I mucked with it.

Comment: @BrianRoach yes it works on windows (assuming permisions are ok) it's one of the things Windows inherited from VMS! Can't have UNC paths with Unix, you need a local mount point for NFS

Comment: Ooo ok that makes so much more sense for why '/' is used, I'm still in college, if you can't tell, but doing an internship right now, if professors would actually explain things like you did my life would be alot easier! 
So do I actually put domain? Or is it supposed to be something that refences the machine being used? What I need this to do is be able to be used by different users on different machines but they all save to the same folder same file overriding the previous file saved when this is called

Comment: @gary - there is a lot of backward compatibility, mistakes we need to work around and stuff that is wrong but we can't change in the field.

Comment: What do you mean? I have compatibility problems in my code? and do you mean we can't change in the field as in we can't change the domain/machine name? My plan is that the application is going to be saved on the server and users will create a Shortcut on their desk tops from that. I'm not sure if that helps or works around "changing in the field" though??

Comment: @Gary - I was replying to your comment about not being taught this. For a subject only a generation old - the field of software engineering has a lot of historical baggage that we can't change because it would break "backwards compatibility" ;-)

Comment: Ooo haha I feel dumb. I'm fine with it the way it is I just wish the professors would explain it instead of just saying "When specifying a path you have to use / instead of \" and ignore ?s about it. 
But what about doing this when it is going to be used on multiple computers to save to the same location on the server? I can't put in a machine name since it will be more than 1

Comment: @gary "machine name" is the name of server with the share on it - the machine you see when you browse network neighbourhood. You can also use '\\' for '\' but it's confusing to have "\\\\machine\\server\\file" so Windows lets you use / for \

Comment: @MartinBeckett and any others that assisted in answering this, I finally got it to work and just wanted to say thank you. I think I had had my code right some time before I asked this question, which was similar to what was suggested by you but it ended up that the folder I was writting to didnt allow other users to write to it (I know I'm an idiot for not checking that). But you also did clarify my confusion for why '/'s are needed which was very helpful!